# How to add numbering to ToC?

Tags: table-of-contents, numbering

In my report i want to have the numbering like this:
[image]

So I need to change the ToC in a chapter somehow is that right?
So far, this is what I have now:
[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)  that illustrates how you made that TOC, so we can reproduce your situation and show you how it should be changed. Remember: *minimal* but working, i.e.  removing any package, code or text without influence in the format of the TOC, but still starting with `\documentclass{...}`, ending with `\end{document}` ad  compilable as is, without having to complete it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using standard classes you can try with

```
\documentclass{report}
\begin{document}
{\let\oldchapter\chapter
\def\chapter*#1{\oldchapter{#1}}
\tableofcontents}
\chapter{Foo}
\section{Bla}
\chapter{Foo bar}
\section{Bla bla}
\end{document}
```